# What is the difference between the spaces $L^1$($\mu$) and $L^1$(d$\mu$)? And is one a subset of the other?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

What is the difference between the spaces $L^1$($\mu$) and $L^1$(d$\mu$) ? And is one a subset of the other?

$\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Can you write the definition of these spaces? Where did you see these notations?

Comment: these notations are from a hw problem, i don't know what they mean.

Comment: They are both common notation for the same space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Both stand for the [Lebesgue space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces) of integrable functions, up to equality $\mu$-almost everywhere.

The inconsistency of notation originates in the notation for the integral of $f$ with respect to $\mu$: it can be written as
$$\int f(x)\,d\mu(x),\quad \int f\,d\mu, \quad \text{or }\quad \int f\,\mu$$
On one hand, mathematicians prefer single-letter names for objects (such as measures), on the other, they are used to $dx$ in integrals. Hence the inconsistency.